# Error Handling on Contract Calls to Other Contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm trying to call a function from another contract and need a way to accommodate errors.

Say contract A has the method getBalance:

```
    function getBalance(address x) 
      public 
      view 
      returns(uint output)
        { output = Balance(x);}
```

I'd like to call this function and treat a null response as a zero. Currently, I can't get my function to simply revert, in that if I call addressA.getBalance(x), and x or addressA is misspecified, the function reverts and does not allow me to simply assume it is zero. I'd like it to find something like 'try:' in python for solidity.

Note: It's hard to communicate because I just wanted to abstract from contract logic that would be distracting, but that generates sloppy examples (so, thanks for your patience).
Contract A has daughter contracts A(i). Contract B calls Contract A looking for data on A(1), A(2), and A(3). If A(1) doesn't exist, the getter function reverts, and contract B doesn't look for A(2) or A(3). 
I changed the code so that Contract A reports null values if A(i) doesn't exist, so that if A(1) does not exist, it presumes the output is set to default values (zero). 
I did this by adding an if statement within the getter function in contract A that looks to see if A(i) exists:

```
import "./DaughterTemplate";
    .....
    function getter(playerAddress) public view returns (uint data)
    {
        address daughter = activeDaughters[playerAddress];
        if (daughter != address(0)) {
            DaughterTemplate d = DaughterTemplate(daughter);
            data = d.data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. What is "a null response"??? 2. "x or addressA is misspecified" - those are two completely different cases! For `x`, there is no such thing as "misspecified". Any value is legitimate, and your function should (and probably does) return a valid `uint` value. For `addressA` - why would you ever "misspecify" it??? You should show your could and explain how you've managed to write a contract with this case being possible. In any case, you'll have to do that "try thing" in assembly. If you showed your code, then I might be able to explain in more specific details and an actual coding example.

Comment: You can make a low level call with `.call` and `abi.encodeWithSignature`, but it is usually not a good idea.

Comment: say I am calling a function in contract A from contract B, where the argument is an address that has been restricted (eg, 'require(arguementAddress != EricAddress )') . Then if I call that function, my result in the logs of Remix are 
`call to ContractA.callContractB errored: VM error: revert.`
`revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.`
This causes everything to stop within contract B
That’s a silly example, but it also applies if I’m calling, say, another contract that has a totally different ABI (eg, I put in a correct eth address, just it’s the wrong address).

Answer (score 0):

We're all having a hard time understanding this:

> I can't get my function to simply revert, in that if I call addressA.getBalance(x), and x or addressA is misspecified

This part looks malformed:

> output = Balance(x);

You started with:

> getBalance(address x)

This implies that `x` is a contract or EOA.

When you say

> output = Balance(x);

You are instantiating `contract Balance` at `address x`. I understand that such may not be what you intend to do, and I am making educated guesses about the parts of the code you did not show. On the face of it, it makes no sense because:

> output = Balance(x);

and

> returns(uint output)

do not appear to be compatible. You seem to be returning an instance of a contract, cast as a `uint`. That conversion is not possible and it shouldn't compile.

Assuming there is a `contract Balance` with a `function balanceOf(address a)`, where `a` corresponds to an account, then it would look like:

`return Balance(contractAddress).balanceOf(a); // contract address set elsewhere`

A typical Balance contract would not throw if it used something like `mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;` It would just return 0, and invalid addresses should not make it that far.

In case it helps, something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Trivial {

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable {
        uint amount = balances[msg.sender];
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
}

contract Curious {

   function inspect(Trivial trivial, address account) public view returns(uint balance) {
       balance = trivial.balances(account); 
   } 
}
```

Nothing will complain as long as valid addresses are passed in - one for the Trivial contract to check, and one for the account to check.

Hope it helps.